# git log pretty format

Tags: git, format, git-log

I have an alias for `git log` twoline.

```
[alias]
    l       = "log --graph --date=relative --decorate --abbrev-commit --pretty=format:'%h - %aD (%ar)%d%n  %s - %an'"
```

It works nicely.

**output#1:**

```
$ git l -2
* 714a14e - Fri, 18 Nov 2016 00:04:19 -0800 (3 months ago) (HEAD -> dev, github/dev)
|   Adding BitSet implementation. - hippy
* 87dce5f - Sat, 10 Dec 2016 12:50:40 -0800 (9 weeks ago)
|   Turning on recommended code analysis rules. - hippy
```

However, with `--name-status`, I can see a pipe after the author name.

**output#2:**

```
$ git l -2 --name-status
* 714a14e - Fri, 18 Nov 2016 00:04:19 -0800 (3 months ago) (HEAD -> dev, github/dev)
|   Adding BitSet implementation. - hippy|
| M README.md
| A rm.Extensions/BitSet.cs
| M rm.Extensions/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
| M rm.Extensions/rm.Extensions.csproj
| A rm.ExtensionsTest/BitSetTest.cs
| M rm.ExtensionsTest/rm.ExtensionsTest.csproj

* 87dce5f - Sat, 10 Dec 2016 12:50:40 -0800 (9 weeks ago)
|   Turning on recommended code analysis rules. - hippy|
| M rm.Extensions/GraphExtension.cs
| M rm.Extensions/Wrapped.cs
| M rm.Extensions/WrappedExtension.cs
| M rm.Extensions/rm.Extensions.csproj
```

If I were to add a `%n` at the very end (so `...%an%n`), **output#1** becomes 3 lines instead of 2.

I want `--name-status` to look like this preferably but an extra newline before list of files is ok:

```
$ git l -2 --name-status
* 714a14e - Fri, 18 Nov 2016 00:04:19 -0800 (3 months ago) (HEAD -> dev, github/dev)
|   Adding BitSet implementation. - hippy
| M README.md
| A rm.Extensions/BitSet.cs
| M rm.Extensions/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
| M rm.Extensions/rm.Extensions.csproj
| A rm.ExtensionsTest/BitSetTest.cs
| M rm.ExtensionsTest/rm.ExtensionsTest.csproj
|
* 87dce5f - Sat, 10 Dec 2016 12:50:40 -0800 (9 weeks ago)
|   Turning on recommended code analysis rules. - hippy
| M rm.Extensions/GraphExtension.cs
| M rm.Extensions/Wrapped.cs
| M rm.Extensions/WrappedExtension.cs
| M rm.Extensions/rm.Extensions.csproj
```

This just seems like a bug to me as I cannot find anything in the [pretty formats man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats).

```
$ git version
git version 2.11.0.windows.1
```

How do I fix this the `pretty format`?

Note: I have filed a bug here ([bug link](http://marc.info/?t=148695424800002&r=1&w=2)) and will update the ticket accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly a bug (the vertical bar is in the wrong *place*; note the gap below the `--name-status` items).  Fortunately, there is a trivial workaround: use `tformat` instead of plain `format`.  The difference is that `tformat` adds a newline if needed, and not if not needed.

Note that `--format` (available since Git version 1.6.3) is essentially a synonym for `--pretty=tformat:`, since most user-facing code should usually be using `tformat`.

Comment: I had tried `tformat`. I think `format` with `%n` at the end is better than `tformat` due to readability. I'd have used `git log --graph --decorate --oneline` but it does not output author, dates. I guess I'll report the bug in the meantime.

Comment: But as you noted, an explicit `%n` (`%an%n`) puts in a newline when you don't want it, as well as when you do ("output #1 becomes 3 lines..."). With `tformat`, it doesn't.